# What is the best way to run a background process in Django?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

I need to do the following things in Django Rest API.

When the user sends a request, update the database with request info and run a Python process in the background, which will update the database after completion (**Here I, No need to wait until the process has been completed**). Need to return a response quickly to the user.

**Described in Steps:**
When the request comes in

1. Update the database with request info
2. Call python process (no need to wait)
3. Return response

I want to know what is the best way to achieve this (Running background task).

Here I want to run the task in the background. not in a scheduled manner.

Kindly let me know the best possible way. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you check [Celery](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/getting-started/introduction.html). It allows you to start jobs running in the background. It should do the trick.